# Save list of data item by item to model instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Im creating a website that allows users to follow stocks and see articles based on what they follow. I createded a page to follow stocks by selecting checkboxes, pass that data into `stocks_user_selected` as a list, but am then unsure how to save the information to the database. Thanks in advance.

models.py:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed_stocks = models.ManyToManyField(Stock, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()
```

views.py:

```
def follow_stocks_post_registration(request):
    all_stocks = Stock.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        stocks_user_selected = request.POST.getlist('stocks_selected')
        for stock in stocks_user_selected:
            request.user.profile.followed_stocks = request.user.profile.followed_stocks + stock #???  


    return render(request, 'core/post_registration_stock_following.html', {'all_stocks': all_stocks})
```

The form used to get the data:

```
{% block head %}
    <title>Next step follow stocks</title>
{% endblock %}

{%  block body %}
    <form action ="{% url 'follow_stocks_post_registration' %}" method="post" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for stock in all_stocks %}
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{ stock.name }}" name="stocks_selected">{{ stock }}
            <br/>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type = "submit" value="Submit"></button>
    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're posting the names of the selected stocks, so load each one by name and add it to `followed_stocks` - using the `add()` method.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    stocks_user_selected = request.POST.getlist('stocks_selected')
    user_profile = request.user.profile
    for stock_name in stocks_user_selected:
        stock = Stock.objects.get(name=stock_name)
        user_profile.followed_stocks.add(stock)
    user_profile.save()
```

Comment: I am trying this but it is not saving the info to the database

Comment: Try explicitly saving the user profile. I have updated the answer and refactored it slightly.